# Identical execve causes "Permission denied" for one program but not another

Tags: exec, thunderbird, devuan

Permission denied shows up when I try to open some attachment in Thunderbird.  Yet, it doesn't look as a Thunderbird bug, because when I `strace` the process I see it issues the correct call.  Yet it fails.

```
11545 execve("/usr/local/bin/libreoffice6.4", ["libreoffice6.4", "--writer", "file:///tmp/user/1000/via%20alla%20quite%2012%20Laigueglia"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "WINDOWID=18874383", "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1", "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0", "XTERM_VERSION=XTerm(344)", ... ]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Permissions are good, I tested with `namei` and `getfacl`.  Then I copied the `execve` instruction from `strace -v -s 1024` to a C file and compiled it.  In that case, it succeeds.  Every time I run it by mouse clicks in Thunderbird it fails, every time I run the following test program it succeeds.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *path="/usr/local/bin/libreoffice6.4";
    char *argv[] =
    {
        "libreoffice6.4",
        "--writer",
        "file:///tmp/user/1000/via%20alla%20quite%2012%20Laigueglia",
        NULL
    };
    char *envp[] =
    {
        "SHELL=/bin/bash",
        "WINDOWID=18874383",
        "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1",
        "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0",
        "XTERM_VERSION=XTerm(344)",
        // ...
        NULL
    };
    int rtc = execve(path, argv, envp);
    perror("execve failed");
    return rtc;
}
```

Note that Thunderbird can open a number of attachments correctly.  Only LibreOffice and a custom shell program fail, thus far.  Both are not part of the stock distribution — Devuan Beowulf — but this cannot explain the failure, can it?

There is no point reporting the bug to Thunderbird, because it is an old 68 version, and the bug may be fixed already or perhaps will disappear spontaneously on the next install.  Certainly, I cannot report it if I have no clue of what the heck goes wrong.  I don't understand how come the access is alternately denied and granted.

- I run Thunderbird and the straw man program under the same userid/ session.
- Thunderbird doesn't seem to call any of `trace=setuid,setfsuid,setreuid`.
- The `x` bit is on on each part of the relevant paths.
- I never used ACLs.

Edit: The man page for `execve` lists four possible reasons for **`EACCESS`**:

- Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix of filename or the name of a script interpreter.
- The file or a script interpreter is not a regular file.
- Execute permission is denied for the file or a script or ELF interpreter.
- The filesystem is mounted noexec.

None of those appears to be true.  I complicated the straw man program adding dummy `thread_creation`s and `fork`s to mimic Thunderbird behavior.  In particular, running this executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14328 Nov  6  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-launch-desktop
```

Note that it is part of `libglib2.0-0:amd64`, not Thunderbird.

Still, I cannot reproduce the failure as experienced by Thunderbird.

Edit2: Submitted the case against libc6 to both [Devuan bug 497](https://bugs.devuan.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=497) and [Debian bug 966343](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=966343)

Comment: "intermittently" is a misleading word to use for _every time that I do this it happens_.

Comment: @JdeBP The point is that doing the same thing the result differs as in hysteresis.  Since *hysterically* means something different, I tried intermittently.  Is there a better word?

Comment: Not sure why this question scored a down vote.  Besides the misuse of a single word it seems a good question.

Comment: Apparmor policies or similar restrictions in play?

Answer (score 1):

*This is a theory, not a conclusive answer...*

There are other reasons for Permission Denied. The one that springs to mind is [AppArmor](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse).  I've not checked to see if this affects Thunderbird on your distro.  It should write to the syslog when blocking a program's access so check `/var/log/syslog`.

This would neatly explain your issue because AppArmor is configured per program and by default will let unknown programs do whatever they like.  Thunderbird *might* have an AppArmor profile preventing it from executing other programs (OpenOffice).  Your own test program would not have such a profile.

Comment: Correct.  Mark Hindley also [pointed out](https://bugs.devuan.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=498#8) this solution.  This reason is not documented in execve man page.

Comment: @Ale Yes I think it's not documented because it's provided by an extension (Kernal Module).  It wouldn't be possible to document every extension on a single man page.  That said, the man page *could* mention security extensions since they are prevelent.

Comment: I doubt all security modules result in similar failures.  For example, returning EACCES whenever permission is denied, and not, say, EPERM.  LSM hooks seem to leave too much rope to extensions, thereby impeding a precise general documentation.